# Closed form for a generating function of the form $f(t) = t^k$ or more general: $f$ some polynomial

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions

I'm looking for a closed form for 
$G(x) = \sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty} f(t) x^t$ for f(t) of the form $f(t) = t^a$
or more general $f(t) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{d} a_i t^i$.

I know there are forms for $f(t) = t$ and $f(t) = t^2$ and $f(t) = t^3$.

bg,
Johannes

Comment: Look up the polylogarithm.

Answer (score 0):

See e.g. Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). For the generating function for the sequence $< p(k) a_k >$, given the generating function $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, you get:
$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} p(n) a_n z^n
  = p(z D) A(z)
$$
where $D$ is the derivative. I.e., to get the generating function for $< n^2 >$,
start with:
$$
G(z) = \frac{1}{1 - z} = \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n
$$
and then:
$$
z \frac{d}{d z} \left( z \frac{d}{d z} \frac{1}{1 - z} \right)
 = \frac{z + z^2}{(1 - z)^3}
$$

Comment: thnx for the formula, I did not know it.

Comment: But I dont really understand your example. you start with the serisa $a_k$ = 1, sure. then $p(k) = k^2$. I would say the result of $p(zD)f$ would be $ (zD)^2 \frac{1}{1-z}$ why is this the same as in your example?

Comment: Does $p(zD)f$ mean, we apply $p(zD)$ on $f$ instead of multiply it by each other? In this case I knew the result. But that's not what I am looking for. I'm looking for a *closed form* like $G(z) = \frac{z + z^2}{1 - z^3}$ in the example above for general exponents.

Comment: @Johannes, $(z D)^2 = z D (z D) = z^2 D^2 + z D$. You apply the "derivative, multiply by $z$" several times.

Comment: @Johannes, using [Bernoulli's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) will get you a formula for the sum of any (positive, integer) power.